# Incorrect date input being stored within state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime

I am getting confused with javascript dates but within my app, I am using the following npm package: [rc-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-datepicker)

Here the user clicks on a date, which is 21/11/2021 but for some reason, within state, it is being stored as:

```
2021-11-20T23:25:43.223Z
```

which is the day prior.

I have got a console log of the date that is being passed through, which is in the following format:

```
Sun Nov 21 2021 10:25:46 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Can someone pls assist on how to ensure that the 21/11/2021 is returned and ignore the timezone, if that is the issue or something else?

Comment: `+1100` It's simply UTC vs local time (but the same moment in time)

Comment: @pilchard - based on this as I am confused, can you pls let me know what I need to apply/do, to obtain the actual date selected as I need to store this 21/11/2021 within the backend DB?

Comment: If you just want to store the string you can output it from the returned date before storing `date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB')` see: [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString). Keep in mind that without explicitly providing a timezone it will use the timezone of the users local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are on AEDT (me too!) your dates will show in your timezone.

As pilchard mentioned in the comment, 2021-11-20T23:25:43.223Z is GMT so that's like the start point. Us being +11 means those two representations of time above are actually at the same point in time.

Let's look at what happens with those dates you have.

If you call:

```js
const d = new Date("2021-11-20T23:25:43.223Z")
console.log(d.toString()) // Prints the local representation: Sun Nov 21 2021 10:25:43 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)

console.log(d.toISOString()) // Prints in ISO formatted string
```

Have a look at other [date object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#instance_methods).

So store that string (eg. "2021-11-20T23:25:43.223Z") which represents the same point in time anywhere in the world. Then convert it to the user's local timezone

```js
const d = new Date("2021-11-20T23:25:43.223Z")
```

You can use other methods such as `toLocaleDateString` in the link above to specify a particular timezone. The timezone component can be one from the tz database. There is a [list of them on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).